# Как задержать исполнение onItemSelected в ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Как сделать так, чтобы при быстром переключении в ListView, выполнялось только действие, соответствующее пункту, на котором пользователь задержался на некоторое время(например, на 300 мс), а те, что быстро перелистнулись, игнорировались?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       //Делаем что нужно
    }
 };

Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 300);//Даем команду выполнить через 300мс
```

не то?

Comment: Ну, почти то)) Только как сделать так, чтобы в Handler'е могла выполняться только одна задача, то есть если запостить следующую, а предыдущая на паузе, то старая удаляется?

Comment: нет, postDelayed в данном случае нужно привязывать к одному из View-классов. Но да, можно и так делать задержки.

Answer (score 4):

Решение найдено. Я сделала, как советовал [[@katso](/users/6520/katso)](/users/6520/katso), только еще прописала:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)  { 
    savedItem = position;
    //Удаляем все отложенные задания
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(mMyRunnable);
    //Задаем новое
    myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable,300); }
```

Здесь в глобальный `savedItem` сохраняется номер выбранного пункта, а в `mMyRunnable.run()` код выполняется в зависимости от этого сохраненного номера.

Answer (score 3):

Задержать выполнение можно вызвав Thread.sleep(3000), где 3000 - миллисекунды, то бишь 3 секунды. Но задерживать поток UI(он же главный, он же текущий по-умолчанию) - это перебор, не делайте так **никогда**. Можно написать кастомную анимацию для выбранного View и анимацию для самого списка.

К примеру, выбрав элемент списка, анимация для выбранного вью его увеличит, а анимация списка уберет все остальные. Но тут нужно все продумать детально, ибо их взаимодействие - задача порой не простая.

Comment: Мне как раз нужно, чтобы UI был свободным. Он же начинает выполнять тяжелый onItemSelected(запуск видео) для каждого пункта, попадающего в фокус, поэтому анимация списка тормозит. Можно, конечно, сделать запуск по клику, но это не вписывается в концепцию интерфейса.
Еще можно запускать тяжелую задачу в отдельном потоке с нужной задержкой, а если запускается задача для следующего пункта, то поток останавливается и очищается, и туда постится следующая задача... 
А VideoView.start() запустится не в UI? Но тогда можно, чтобы тред только посылал сообщение по истечении паузы. Костыли какие-то.

Comment: Опишите задачу более детально и простым языком. Тяжеловато было понимать, что конкретно вы хотите, поэтому и ответ получился в общих чертах.

Comment: Извините, это я... погрузилась))
Попробую еще раз))
Когда выбран пункт ListView, вызывается функция onItemSelected, присоединеного OnItemSelectedListener'а. Так?
Если переключать пункты быстро, то и соответствующие функции будут вызывать быстро друг за другом. Например, у меня быстро переключаются видео, соответствующие пунктам меню. От этого сам список тормозит.
Нужно, чтобы видео запускалось только тогда, когда пользователь задерживается на пункте списка.
Можно делать костыли, но нет ли возможности слушать только долгое удержание выбора?

Comment: Теперь понятнее. Ну есть onLongItemSelected, но это именно долгий клик на пункте(тап), что в вашем случае не годится. Не понятно, зачем вообще они у вас сразу воспроизводяться, ну да ладно. Тут просто не угадаешь виличину задержки в таком случае. Долго это сколько? Может я выбрал раз 300мс, потом 500 и варироваться может очень по-разному. Попробуйте пошаманить с selectedItem.postDeleyed(), но я думаю вам саму идею менять нужно.

Comment: Поменять идею не получится, она не моя. User case должен быть следующий: пользователь нажимает на пульте клавиши вверх/вниз -- переключаются каналы, то есть как привычно на обычном телевизоре. В ListView, соответственно, список каналов, который может быть показан, а может быть скрыт. Как то так.))
Я нашла решение, ниже напишу. Спасибо за помощь =)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте сделать так.

1. Заводите список отложенных задач.
2. По приходу пользователя к пункту ListView, добавляете задачу в список и запускаете таймер.
3. По уходу пользователя из пункта ListView, выкидываете задачу из списка (если она ещё там есть) и останавливаете таймер (если ещё не остановлен).
4. По приходу таймера, если задача ещё не выкинута из списка, выполняете задачу и останавливаете таймер.

Вроде должно работать.

Если есть возможность подписаться на "длинный" hover/touch, конечно воспользуйтесь именно им, и не переизобретайте велосипед.

---

Если воспользоваться упомянутым [[@katso](/users/6520/katso)](/users/6520/katso) `postDelayed`, можно сделать так:

1. Каждому заданию назначаем глобальный ID типа, скажем, `long`.
2. В `new Runnable()` запоминаем уникальный ID в final-поле; запоминаем этот ID в поле `long activeID`.
3. В методе `Run` проверяем, совпадает ли его `ID` с `activeID`; если нет, прекращаем выполнение.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ.